# how to select row using mysql, php and json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a problem getting a format that I need in JSON.

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "******", "******");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db("highchart", $con);
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM trafico");
$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Time';
$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'Tx';
$series2 = array();
$series2['name'] = 'Rx';

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $category['data'][] = $r['time_1m'];
    $series1['data'][] = $r['Tx'];
    $series2['data'][] = $r['Rx'];
}
$result = array();
array_push($result, $category);
array_push($result, $series1);
array_push($result, $series2);
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This is what I am expecting to get as a result:

```
[{
"name": "Time",
"data": ["2018-03-28 17:57:01", "2018-03-28 17:58:01", "2018-03-28 17:59:01", "and so on...."]
}, {
"name": "Tx",
"data": [1025.14, 1056.14, 1035.14, 1042.14, 1038.14, and so on...]
}, {
"name": "Rx",
"data": [52, 54, 51, 49, 46, 48, 53, 56, , and so on...]
}]
```

but the result I am getting at the moment is:

```
[{"name":"Time"},{"name":"Tx"},{"name":"Rx"}]
```

I can't figure out why I'm not getting the result I'm looking for.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should `var_dump()` the result arrays in the loop, to see where you're getting at. // On a quick glance it seems to be the assignment to a non-existant subarray (`$series["data"][]` cannot be appended to when uninitialized). // There are better ways to structure this anyhow.

Comment: I'm always open to better ways, pretty new to this so any help pointing me on the right direction greatly appreciated.